# Looking for a book about dog rescued from scientists, then kids get superpowers with red eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel

It’s  about a dog or some kind of dog-like creature that was getting tested on in a science lab and looked like he was about to die and then a girl (maybe with friends) saves it. They learn it had some kind of disease and the kids get weird symptoms and they get red eyes sometimes. The go to school or something and they go to a party (I'm not sure, but I feel like they meet a guy named Chance or with last name Chancellor). In like the 1st or 2nd book or something, he gets the disease too on purpose with like blue eyes or something like that. Anyone know the name?

Comment: What superpowers do the kids get? Can they fly? Do they have X-ray vision? Can they make themselves invisible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Virals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virals_(novel)) by Kathy Reichs and its [sequels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virals).

> It’s about a dog or some kind of dog-like creature that was getting tested on in a science lab and looked like he was about to die and then a girl (maybe with friends) saves it.

Tory and her friends rescue a wolfdog puppy from the lab on Loggerhead Island.

> They learn it had some kind of disease and the kids get weird symptoms
>   and they get red eyes sometimes.

He's been experimented on and is suffering from parvo.  The kids all catch parvo (obviously it's a weird mutated strain of parvo) and when they recover they have super speed, strength and senses.

> The go to school or something and they go to a party (I'm not sure,
>   but I feel like they meet a guy named Chance or with last name
>   Chancellor). In like the 1st or 2nd book or something, he gets the disease too on purpose with like blue eyes or something like that.

One of the other students at the school the kids attend is Chance Claybourne, whose family is connected to the experiments on the wolfdog.  (I don't have the book in front of me, but I think they went to a party with Chance at some point.)  He gets the same superparvo as the main characters in one of the later books.